# Change menu title in sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, menu, sharepoint-2010

I want to change menu and link titles in sharepoint 2010 and I change some links titles:

[image]

I change `Home` to `Casa` using `Site Settings-->Title, Description and Icon` but `Home` in under menu didnot change. How I can change this menu title?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings.
Click "Top Link Bar" under "Look and Feel" section.
Here you can edit the caption of the link as required.